# get the real file name from temp

Tags: c#, .net

I have a small project that functions to saves and deal with all new items that enter it in a folder.

My problem is that when items from Gmail are transferred to this folder the attachment name gets new extensions that are not recognized, and then cannot be located as they are not the original name.

For example it comes as `AAA.PDF.GGG.ORT`, when it is filed as `AAA.PDF`.

How can I get the real file name, without the added extensions?

Comment: The most reliable way would be to inspect the file itself. PDFs, JPEGs, GIFs, DOCXs, etc. all have unique headers within the first few bytes that give away their file type.

Comment: How are those file-names created? Why is `GGG.ORT` added, it it always the same, do you know a list of possible extensions added, is the `FileNameWithoutExtension` always `AAA` or can it also contain a dot like in `AAA.BBB.PDF`?

Comment: @Brad Christie unfortunately this is very unreliable. Unlike on *NIX on windows are many file formats without a unique _magic_ (i.e. the first few bytes do not say anything about the file type)

Comment: The added file-name extensions are created through the temporary folder in the computer. I don't have a list of possible extensions. The original file name is always with only one extension Ex: AAA.PDF or DDD.JPEG

Comment: You can use `Contains` on the full file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The original file name is always with only one extension Ex: AAA.PDF
>   or DDD.JPEG

Then it is easy:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullName); // "AAA.PDF.GGG.ORT"
string[] fileNameToken = fileName.Split('.');
string originalFileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", fileNameToken[0], fileNameToken[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much and successfully

Answer (score 0):

Presuming there's some pattern to the number of characters after the 'real' file extension, I would use a sub string function similar to convert the file name.

Comment: Currently this "answer" is not very helpful, is it?